# Passing a byte array inside bundle becomes null

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm trying to pass a byte array from activity A to activity B but for some reason the variable suddenly becomes null. I've been trying to figure out what's going on but I haven't found a solution, maybe you can help me.
Here is my code for activity A:

```
    @Override
public void respond( String desc_plato, byte[] imag_plato ){
        System.out.println("des plato: "+desc_plato);
        System.out.println("image plato: "+imag_plato);

        if( imag_plato != null )
        {
            System.out.println("HERE IMAG_PLATO IS NOT NULL");
        }

        Intent intentDetalle = new Intent( this, PlatosDetalle.class );
        intentDetalle.putExtra("desc_plato", desc_plato);
        intentDetalle.putExtra("imag_plato ", imag_plato);
        startActivity( intentDetalle );
    }
}
```

Code on activity B:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // excluding common code here... then:
    System.out.println("PlatosDetalle onCreate");

    Bundle PlatosIntent = getIntent().getExtras();
    String desc_plato = PlatosIntent.getString("desc_plato");
    byte[] imagen_plato = PlatosIntent.getByteArray("imag_plato");
    // I GOT THIS CODE FROM ANOTHER ANSWER, TO CHECK KEYS ON INTENT
    /**************************************************/
    for (String key : PlatosIntent.keySet()) {
        Object value = PlatosIntent.get(key);
        System.out.println("BUNDLE KEYS:"+ String.format("%s %s\n", key,  
            value.toString()));
    }
    System.out.println( imagen_plato );
    /************************************************/


    if( imagen_plato == null )
    {
        System.out.println("HERE IMAGEN_PLATO IS NULL");
        finish();
    }
}
```

In code for activity B, even right after printing the keys->values in the for loop the variable "imagen_plato" is already null...

Here is my logCat, or at least the logs I do with System.out.println:

```
04-16 02:04:35.915: I/System.out(5072): des plato: Pizza especial para clientes vegetarianos
04-16 02:04:35.925: I/System.out(5072): image plato: [B@41a80170
04-16 02:04:35.925: I/System.out(5072): HERE IMAG_PLATO IS NOT NULL
04-16 02:04:35.955: I/Choreographer(5072): Skipped 132 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-16 02:04:36.015: I/System.out(5072): PlatosDetalle onCreate
04-16 02:04:36.015: I/System.out(5072): BUNDLE KEYS:desc_plato Pizza especial para clientes vegetarianos
04-16 02:04:36.015: I/System.out(5072): BUNDLE KEYS:imag_plato  [B@41757c48
04-16 02:04:36.015: I/System.out(5072): null
04-16 02:04:36.015: I/System.out(5072): HERE IMAGEN_PLATO IS NULL
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!!!

Comment: Try to remove space after key "imag_plato" from put byte data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
 intentDetalle.putExtra("imag_plato ", imag_plato);
                                   ^
```

Passing space with `imag_plato` key name. use key with-out space character :

```
intentDetalle.putExtra("imag_plato", imag_plato);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I can't believe i didn't see it :s I'd been struggling with this for hours, way too long in front of the monitor i guess.. thank you again!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

As @ρяσѕρєя-k pointed out, use proper key to put and get the byte array. Better to create some constants and use them in your code as key, so that you don't have to type your keys as literals every time. This will help in removing all these kind of problems in future.